# Oracle SQL Developer 4.2.0.17.089.1709 wont open - no errors

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have downloaded:

`Oracle SQL Developer 4.2.0.17.089.1709` Windows 32-bit/64-bit version

Extracted it to a Windows 7 SP1 32 bit machine to the C drive `C:\sqldeveloper`

When I run `sqldeveloper.exe` nothing happens.

EDIT:

I have also installed JRE 1.8.131 `jre-8u131-windows-i586` & JDK 1.8.131 `jdk-8u131-windows-i586`

> Congratulations!
>   You have the recommended Java installed (Version 8 Update 131).

Running it in `CMD` by using:

`cd C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin` and running `sqldeveloper.exe` and  get the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file `C:\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar`

Comment: Can you start it in CMD window? May be some useful log appears.

Comment: 1. Type "cmd" in Win 7 search bar. 2) Change directory where your SQL Developer is placed ("cd" command). 3) Type "sqldeveloper.exe"

Comment: Nothing happens, i changed directory `cd C:\sqldeveloper` then ran `sqldeveloper.exe` and it just starts a new line

Comment: @hinotf Ok i ran it by using the location `C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin` and running `sqldeveloper.exe` then i got an error which i will put in my question.

Comment: Try to edit C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf and revise line started with "SetJavaHome". This should be point to correct jdk directory. For example, in my configuration file (Win 7 64, SQLDev 4.1) "SetJavaHome ../../jdk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubleshooting it ended up being an issue with having multiple versions of JRE & JDK installed (both `1.8.121` and `1.8.131` for JDK & JRE).

I deleted the older `1.8.121` fodlers and re ran `sqldeveloper.exe` and it asked me again for the location of JDK, pointed it to the `1.8.131` folder and it worked.