# Cannot launch SQL Developer 4.2

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

A Windows server A contains SQL Developer 4.2. When I double click on its exe file, nothing happens, not even a flash screen. When I try to run the exe from the command prompt, nothing happens too, not even an error message.

From server A, I mapped a drive from server B. So now server B's F:\ drive is now Y:\ in server A. Server B also has SQL Developer 4.2 in its F:. If I login to server B, I can launch SQL Developer 4.2 from its F:. But when in server A, I cannot launch SQL Developer 4.2 from the Y:\ drive.

In server A, if I open command window and enter "java -version", I get Java 1.7.

How do I get SQL Developer 4.2 to work in server A? It is frustrating when there is not even an error message. I have been googling for an answer, but so far nothing works.

Comment: Which EXE are you running - there's a small `sqldeveloper.exe` in the top level, but if you go down to `sqldeveloper\bin` there are several others; do they all behave the same? Is SQL Developer's [JDK path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24391298/266304) set correctly? Is a log file being produced, by SQL Developer or by Java? And do other Java apps run normally?

Comment: I tried the sqldeveloper.exe in the top level, also the sqldeverloper.exe in the subfolder sqldeveloper\bin\. Nothing happen for both when I double click.

Comment: I tried sqldeverloper\bin\sqldeveloper64.exe and I tried sqldeverloper\bin\sqldeveloper64W.exe, and in both cases, an error message pops up "Unable to launch Java Virtual Machine... Located at path ..\sqldeveloper_4_2\jdk\bin\msvcr100.dll".

Comment: Where is SQL Developer's JDK path set? How do I know whether a log file is produced and where to look?

Comment: Sounds like you're on a 32-bit Windows installation I think. I was going to point you to [this](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/06/how-to-collect-debug-info-for-oracle-sql-developer/) but you aren't getting that far. Deleting and re-downloading sometimes helps but not sure that explains the `Y:` issue; that maybe makes it sound like a Java issue... But @thatjeffsmith hangs out here sometimes, hopefully he'll have some better ideas and guidance.

Comment: Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44718104/266304) - do you maybe have multiple JREs and/or JDKs installed?

Comment: Server A has its own copy of SQL Developer in E:\ drive. This doesn't launch. The Y:\ copy is mapped to Server B's copy (in Server B's F:\ drive) and this also doesn't launch in Server A. If I go to Server B, I can launch Server's B SQL Developer from its F:\ drive.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think it's a Java issue on server A. See previous comment...

Comment: There is an older version of SQL Deverloper (3.0) in Server A's E:\ drive. This version can launch. However, this verson is too old and it is not compatible with the Oracle database that I want to connect to. That's why I need to use version 4.2

Comment: Google the DLL error, you'll see the solution.